# How to get the laplacian matrix for a directed weighted network using networkX?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, networkx

I am facing the problem that when I am changing the weights it is not reflected in the laplacian matrix

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
#construction of directed graph
g=nx.DiGraph()
#adding weights to the links
g.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,0.65), (3,1,0.35),(2,3,0.85)])
#extracting the 
L = nx.directed_laplacian_matrix(g)

L = nx.directed_laplacian_matrix(g)
print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour arises because the `DiGraph` is a triangle:

[image]

If an additional edge is added:

[image]

the Laplacian reflects the weights:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,0.65), (3,1,0.35), (2,3,0.85), (3,4,0.2)])
nx.directed_laplacian_matrix(G)
Out[1]:
matrix([[ 0.9875    , -0.45383656, -0.35847072, -0.10930101],
        [-0.45383656,  0.9875    , -0.45936416, -0.10267954],
        [-0.35847072, -0.45936416,  0.9875    , -0.34072508],
        [-0.10930101, -0.10267954, -0.34072508,  0.75      ]])
```

If an edge weight is updated, the Laplacian reflects this:

```
G[3][1]['weight'] = 0.8
nx.directed_laplacian_matrix(G)
Out[2]:
matrix([[ 0.9875    , -0.47030901, -0.41990635, -0.0840537 ],
        [-0.47030901,  0.9875    , -0.47223262, -0.08179532],
        [-0.41990635, -0.47223262,  0.9875    , -0.25329959],
        [-0.0840537 , -0.08179532, -0.25329959,  0.75      ]])
```

Comment: Is there is any direct method to extract the Laplacian matrix of a weighted directed graph?